# The type 'L:StringValidation' was not found error

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

Sorry for my english.
I have a problem with WPF, and so have the application, where it wants to implement validation controls. I created a class `StringValidation` that inherits from the `ValidationRule`. There, I implemented the method validation. in XAML while I did something like this:

```
<TextBox Height="23" Margin="53,39,0,0" Name="txtNazwa" VerticalAlignment="Top" TabIndex="3" MaxLines="1" GotFocus="txtNazwa_GotFocus" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="218"
                         ToolTip="Nazwa wybranej roli" Style="{StaticResource textBoxError}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource errorTemplate}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Nazwa" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <s:StringValidation ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"
                                                              ValidationStep="RawProposedValue"
                                                              ErrorMessage="Error"
                                                              TylkoNiePuste="True"
                                                              />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

And everything started working, so I think that is ok, whereas in the designer crashes error:

> Error 1 The type 's:StringValidation' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

where I added:

```
xmlns:s="clr-namespace:MOJA.Kontrolka.Admin"
```

where the namespace is consistent with the StringValidation class. I do not know what it is, a very difficult job to me. Any suggestions where is the problem and how to fix / avoid?

Comment: try to build all your solution, and be sure that your validator is public. This custom validator should inherit from CustomValidationRule .

Comment: I builded all solution everytime, the error persists. CustomValidationRule is not exists, I would have to implement this class, but this is a problem?

Comment: sorry it's ValidationRule, not CustomValidationRule. have you this problem whe  running the app ?

Comment: StringValidation inherit from ValidationRule.
`public class StringValidation : ValidationRule`

Comment: Does the error persist when you restart Visual Studio?

Comment: No, when I restart VS2010 error is the same.